# Sublime text 3 Latex autocomplete issue

Tags: auto-completion

I use sublime text 3 for Latex. Whenever I use autocomplete say I wrote `\section{` then hit enter what sublime text suggests, I end up having `section{}` without `\` sign in front. Am I missing something? Why each time `\` drops from command when I choose a suggestion from autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. I want to update!

I uninstall latextools. I install Latexing, everything seems working. Latextool seems more popular in SBT3 but in my case, Latexing works better.